# How do I invoke Smartbear ssh from my application without root?

Tags: android, permissions, root

I am trying to invoke `ssh` from my C++ NDK application via `popen()` on a command that does `ssh` which works fine on other platforms.  On Android I get an error when reading the pipe:

```
sh: ssh: not found
```

Therefore, I used the full pathname to the Smartbear `ssh` I have installed, but it still fails:

```
sh: /data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/dropbear/ssh: not found
```

I then tried from an ADB shell but that command only works if I first `su` to `root`. So I guess I don't have permission to see the file system where `ssh` is installed.  Can my app request `su` permissions, if so, what is the api, and will that resolve the failure to invoke `ssh`?

How should I go about invoking `ssh` from my application via `popen()`?  How do I control the permissions and can I get `ssh` into the `PATH` somehow?  Can I install Smartbear in a different way so that root is not needed to access `ssh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put simply: if you're seeing this error, you can't.

App A can't access the data of app B unless app B has explicitly allowed it (via https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).